# multiple filters js arrays of conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, lodash

Been hours I am trying to find a solution for my filtering problem. I am building a marketplace on react however on one of the page I need the user to be able to apply multiple filtering. 
For example I have my

```
productsList = [{brand: 'Zara', category: 'Jeans', color: 'blue'}, {brand: 'BlaBla',color: 'blue', category: 'Leggins'}, {brand: 'Louis', category: 'Leggins', color: 'red'}, {brand: 'Louis', category: 'Jeans', color: 'pink'}]
```

I have many filters that I can access in my state through an object of filters

```
filters: {
  designers: ['Zara', 'Louis'],
  categories: [],
  colors: ['pink']
}
```

For example if I want to keep only the Jeans of Brand Zara and of color blue, how would you advise me to proceed with thee filtering out. I am quite confused because my filters are an object of arrays. I tried using lodash and a couple other solutions I found online but didnt succeed.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should use the array function filter() and create logic within the callback function to only return the values you want:
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/

Comment: your filters need data to define if they are AND, OR conditions, otherwise they have to be coded into your filtering function.  out of curiosity are you using some kind of library or tutorial for this?  I've seen multiple people do this same thing, and the problems have been similar.  Even the code and variable names look the same.

Answer (score 1):

Change the keys of `filters` to fit the objects, or create another object that will translate between the two.

Convert the filters to entries ([key, value]), and filter out empty entries (array is empty). Use `Array.filter()` to iterate the `productList`, and for all existing entries, check if the current object's property is included.

```js
const applyFilters = (filters, arr) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(filters)
    .filter(([, v]) => v.length)
  
  return arr.filter(o => 
    entries
      .every(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k]))
  )
}

const productsList = [{brand: 'Zara', category: 'Jeans', color: 'blue'}, {brand: 'BlaBla',color: 'blue', category: 'Leggins'}, {brand: 'Louis', category: 'Leggins', color: 'red'}, {brand: 'Louis', category: 'Jeans', color: 'pink'}]

const filters = {
  brand: ['Zara', 'Louis'],
  category: [],
  color: ['pink']
}

const result = applyFilters(filters, productsList)

console.log(result)
```

The same idea with your original filter names, and translation to object properties:

```js
const filtersToProps = {
  designers: 'brand',
  categories: 'category',
  colors: 'color'
};

const applyFilters = (filters, arr) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(filters)
    .filter(([, v]) => v.length)
    .map(([k, v]) => [filtersToProps[k], v])
  
  return arr.filter(o => 
    entries
      .every(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k]))
  )
}

const productsList = [{brand: 'Zara', category: 'Jeans', color: 'blue'}, {brand: 'BlaBla',color: 'blue', category: 'Leggins'}, {brand: 'Louis', category: 'Leggins', color: 'red'}, {brand: 'Louis', category: 'Jeans', color: 'pink'}]

const filters = {
  designers: ['Zara', 'Louis'],
  categories: [],
  colors: ['pink']
}

const result = applyFilters(filters, productsList)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
productsList.filter(product => {
    return Object.keys(filters).every(key => {
        if (!filters[key].length) return true;
        switch (key) {
            case 'designers':
                return filters[key].includes(product.brand);
            case 'categories':
                return filters[key].includes(product.category);
            case 'colors':
                return filters[key].includes(product.color);
        }
    })
})
```